# How to interpret ROC plot

Tags: statistics

[image: ROC plot]

In the above plot you have true positives (y - axis), plotted against false positives (x - axis). I've read the wikipedia page on ROC curves but I just don't get it. What does the graph shown above tell me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says you've got yourself one heck of a good test! It's saying that even at 100% specificity (no false positives!), you're also getting almost 100% sensitivity (no false negatives!).

This may help: [Sensitivity vs Specificity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity)

Comment: thank you! I had assumed something along those lines as, the accompanying iterative error and regression error plots show good classification results.

Answer (score 0):

The ROC curves is probqbility of detection (Pd) as function of probability of false alarm (Pfa), and it is depending on the threshold selection, 
The choice of threshold  depends on the approach that we take. If we increase the threshold , PFA and POD go down. Similarly for the inverse.